# SSRS - How to sum a Parameter Expression?

Tags: parameters, sum, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I'm using the below Parameter as an expression in my report to feed a number between 1 & 7. How do I sum this column?

```
=Parameters!NoofBookingsYear1.Value
Expression: [@NoofBookingsYear1]
```

Data is grouped by Season.

Comment: I hate when people question my question but..           
Why do you need to sum your **parameter** - is it a multi-value? You normally would compare it to the sum a field in your data - like for visibility  =IIF(SUM(FIELDS!Bookings.Value) = Parameters!NoofBookingsYear1.Value, True, False)

Comment: Yes, it's basically a multi value parameter [1 - 10] allowing the user to choose potential bookings, which in turn recalculates revenue potential. It groups the data by Season, please see below:-

Comment: Season AVG Rate Potential Bookings  Total Revenue 
Mid          £252                     3                    £755
Off Peak  £174                     3                           £522 
Peak  £469                     3                         £1,407 
Year 1 Target £282             9???                             £845

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's not a built in way to do this. Fortunately, there's Code to work around limitations. You would need some VB code to sum your parameter.

For your expression, you'll want to send all selected amounts of your parameter to the summing function:

```
=code.SumParam(Join(Parameters!q.Value, ", "))
```

For your code, you'll want to parse out the comma and add the numbers:

```
Function SumParam(Param as string) as Decimal

Start:
SumParam = SumParam + Val(Left(Param, INSTR(Param, ",") - 1))

Param = Mid(Param, INSTR(Param, ",") + 1, len(Param))

If INSTR(Param, ",") > 0 Then Goto Start 

SumParam = SumParam  + Val(Param)

End Function
```

I don't have any error checking, so if there's an invalid value, it will probably error out.